# IE 11 position absolute error inside table

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

The ***position:absolute*** inside a table doesn't work correctly, cannot take the full height of the parent container.

Here an example: 
https://jsbin.com/xebizisehu/7/edit?html,css,output

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 6px;

}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
tr {
  /* here height 10 is an example, */
  height: 10rem;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="parent">
              <div class="child">
              Hi
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the message "Hi" is in the center, because child has all height.

In IE11 is on the top, because doesn't have all height.

How can i solve it?

[image]

Here you can see that the height from .child is not all from .parent

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Add `height: 10rem;` to `.child` as well or set the `position` of `.child` to `relative`.

Comment: why do you need position:absolute? to make the text vertical center?

Comment: @Lain I need the son to have the full height of the father, not a fixed height

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs display: flex works

Comment: Why do you need the `div` in the first place then? Just write `Hi` in the `td` and all is centered as desired.

Comment: Just remove `position: absolute` from `child`

Comment: @Lain because the td i can't modify it and i have to work on the div

Comment: @Urel I need absolute for all height and width from parent, heigth: 10rem is an example in my project is dynamic

Comment: And why do you not just set `height: 100%; width: 100%;`

Comment: @Urel: Because it does not work. Anyway as OP can read in the link Phil Andelhofs provided, `display: flex` has certain bugs in IE11. Being stubborn about it wont change a thing.

Comment: Alas in Internet Explorer you have to define an absolute height on either the `td` or the `div`. It does not really regard the height set on rows for children. You can center/middle it without, yet it will not have the full size as actual boundings.

Comment: Tables have been awful and mysterious on any version of ie.

Comment: because td is a table-cell display, position:relative/absolute doesn't work. turn td in a block, then position will work .. but it is not a td anymore :( . flex works indeed fine. **add borders to child to see it, you will understand the bug** - BTW Firefox use to have this issue too with table elements but keeps being updated. IE11 is not supported for too long now .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus can you add a jsbin? I can't change <td> into a <div>

Comment: here is a td turn into block : https://jsbin.com/tuxewiwoxa/1/edit?html,css,output but it is not behaving as a td anymore ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: Your example works because you set a height for `td`. If you do that you dont need to change the display.

Comment: @Lain that's why i said twice it was not a td anymore, it is a bug of an obsolete browser, give it up via css instead wasting time, you can eventually use js to resize correctly the absolute div

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: What Lain probably was trying to point out to you is, that all your comments abot display and table cell being a table cell is irrelevant and does not provide any change to the issue. Only setting the height does the change for IE11, no display required.

Comment: @javascript This is why they are comments and also to demonstrate where the bug stands. ;). How do you retrieve height of a table-cell via css only ?